# Why is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$, where $a_n \in \{0,1,2\}$, bounded by $1/3$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a series of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$$ where $a_n \in \{0,1,2\}$.

Why is this sum bounded by $\frac{1}{3}$? I can not seem to figure out why this series must be less than this value.

It looks like a power series with constant $x$, i.e $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ and with a constraint on the $a_n$'s.

Comment: Clearly it is not bounded above by $1/3$. Let $a_n=2$ for all $n$. Then the sum is $3$, which is the maximum possible value. Did you possibly want to write $3$ and not $1/3$?

Comment: I think that any real number $0\le x\le 1$ can be represented as $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$ where $a_n \in \{0,1,2\}$. Therefore the sum is bounded by 0 and 1.

Comment: Perhaps you meant the index of the sum to start at $n=2$, in which case the sum is bounded by $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: why can any real number $0 \leq x \leq 1$ be written as this series?

Comment: yes i did mean for the index to start at 2 by the way apologies, how do we deduce this bound though?

Answer (score 2):

As clarified in the comments, the sum is supposed to be $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\left(\frac13\right)^n,\ a_n\in\{0,1,2\}$$

Then as a hint, note that

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \min(a_n)\left(\frac13\right)^n\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\left(\frac13\right)^n\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \max(a_n)\left(\frac13\right)^n$$

Hopefully you can finish the rest.